# My JavaScript program doesn't reload picture as quickly as I want

Tags: javascript, http-headers

So I have the following problem: I want my JavaScript to reload an image from my desktop so quickly that the picture in the browser changes as soon as I change/edit the picture on my desktop. It works as intended for maybe the first two times, but then I have to wait a couple of seconds before the picture on my browser changes to the new picture I have on my desktop.

As it's using the same URL, I have a cache breaker so that the browser always loads the new image and I specified at the top as a header that the cache shouldn't store the image, so the browser always checks the image on my desktop. What am I doing wrong? Why isn't it working as intended?

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

<head>
    <title>JavaScript Refresh Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="2000" height="2000"/>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var img = new Image();
    var time = new Date();

    function draw() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    
    function refreshImage() {
        var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        var queryString = "?t=" + timestamp;
        return "Bild1.jpg" + queryString;
    }


    function Animate() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(Animate);
        draw();
        img.src = refreshImage();
    }

    img.onload = function () {
        Animate();
    }

    img.src = refreshImage();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you even accessing the whole thing via HTTP? (If so, then how are you accessing an image on your desktop, with a relative path - your desktop folder would have to be inside the web root then, or somehow linked into there via an ALIAS or something?)

Comment: @CBroe Excuse my inexperience, it's just the first time I work with JavaScript. This isn't originally my code, I just got a `.html` file with the code inside. As for the picture, it is on my desktop, but so is the code. So they're both in the same directory.

Comment: Are you accessing the HTML document via `http://...` in your browser - or did you open it directly via the local file system (address bar should show something like `file:///...` then)?

Comment: every millisecond your code loads the image, you're saturating the network so it's taking a little longer to load and render each time, it would be better if you watch the image for changes then push the new image to the client rather than polling, websockets would be ideal for this but guess you want to keep it simple

Comment: @CBroe I am accessing it directly via the local file system.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone
I will definitely look into this. Any tips on where to look/read up on this? As I said, I am totally blank when it comes to JavaScript.

Comment: _"directly via the local file system"_ - Then I don't see how any "cache buster" could work in the first place. If no HTTP is involved - then there is no HTTP caching either. And I am surprised that with the appended cache buster query string, it even _finds_ the file to begin with - because file systems don't know query strings either.

Comment: What actual _problem_ are you trying to solve with this? ("Live reloading" of a page in the browser, when certain assets change, is something many IDEs have already integrated as a feature.)

Comment: @CBroe What IDEs have this integrated as a feature? Might solve my problem if I look into them.

Comment: Visual Studio, WebStorm etc. from JetBrains, others ... http://livereload.com seems to be mac-only for now, but also looks like a promising candidate for the future (not so much an IDE, but a file system watcher, as far as I can tell.)